# Print div element doesn't work for IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a dynamic div class. The elements inside the div are dynamically populated through backend ajax web service requests. :-

```
<div class="hidden">

       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
        Height="23px" style="margin-top: 0px" Width="69px" text="Print" OnClientClick="PrintElem('#hidden'); return false;"/>
</div>
```

inside this div class, a list of elements that are dynamically populated.
I am trying to use a print button inside this div class to print all elements.

```
function PrintElem(elem) {
            Popup($(elem).html());
        }

        function Popup(data) {
            var mywindow = window.open('', '.hidden', 'height=400,width=600');
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Pharmacy List</title>');
            /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            mywindow.document.write(data);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();

           return true;
        }
```

**This works great for all web browsers except for IE. **

Comment: Try giving the window a name that looks like a valid JavaScript identifier (unlike "#hidden").

Comment: how do you get `class="hidden"` with `#hidden`?

Comment: What's the problem in IE? Can you create a jsfiddle out of your code?

Comment: js fiddle doesn't create the button for me when I copy paste this code. but this is the exact code that I am using.

Comment: its actually '.hidden'

Comment: issue with IE :-  "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid argument."

on line:-

var mywindow = window.open('', '.hidden', 'height=400,width=600');

Comment: @Teemu what do you mean by that?

Comment: Just use `hidden` instead of `.hidden`. Your code works as is in IE9+, but older IEs won't accept a window name beginning with anything else but a letter.

Comment: @Philo if it's anything other than a valid JavaScript identifier, you won't get a window. ".hidden" is not valid.

Comment: so what do you suggest? how did I get a window for safari? firefox? chrome? and not IE ?

Comment: and as @Teemu pointed out if I just use "hidden", a new window opens, but closes almost immediately, without showing any printer controls and options.

Comment: @Philo You need to add `mywindow.focus()` before printing in IE.

Comment: I added mywindow.focus() before mywindow.print() statement, same issue. window opens and closes almost immediately.

Comment: @Philo The document in the pop-up needs to be closed before focusing/printing (beacuse of `document.write()`). Please take a look at Delphian's answer. You may need also use simple `print()` instead of `mywindow.print()`.

Comment: so I used mywindow.document.close().. that stopped the new pop up from closing immediately. However, the new popup seems to be just a generic google search page, instead of my dynamic div class. 

I think this is because, my div class is represented with th e '.hidden' and not just 'hidden'

Comment: I solved it by using this:-

var mywindow = window.open('.hidden', 'hidden', 'height=400,width=600');

I misunderstood the parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code which I'm using to print a DIV content, and its working fine in IE as well,

```
    function printPartOfPage(elementId) {
        var printContent = document.getElementById(elementId);
        var windowUrl = 'Job Receipt';
        var uniqueName = new Date();
        var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
        var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');
        printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.focus();
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();
    }
```

Please try this code